# baseUrl not being found when running cypress tests through Travis CI

Tags: javascript, angular, travis-ci, package.json, cypress

I am trying to run my cypress tests when building a project through Travis CI. I am installing cypress fine, however, I was then getting the following error:

[image: code]I have looked online and in cypress official documentation and the method that they recommend fixing this issue by adding the following into my package.json:

```
"test:ci": "start-server-and-test http://localhost:3000 cy:run"
```

`cy:run` in this case being `cypress run`. However, when I run this, it does build the server however it then does not seem to run the tests afterwards. It just freezes on the build.

I then call this script within my `travis.yml` file as shown:

```
  - npm run test:ci
```

I also have the following as my before_install and install object:

```
before_install:
  - npm i -g npm@5
  - npm i -g firebase-tools
  - npm i -g @angular/cli
  - npm cache verify

install:
  - npm i
  - npm ci
```

To clarify - the desired results is that when running Cypress through Travis, the local server (my baseUrl) is run and then the tests are carried out.

Comment: have the same issue on gitlab ci.

Comment: @ElectRocnic I managed to solve this issue by running a http-server and not local host like so: `"http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors"`

Comment: Thanks, but my setup seems to be completely different from yours, because I already was using nginx as my http-server, and still had the same problem.
My problem was solved through https://stackoverflow.com/a/48288560/3433137 . My setup was a gitlab-ci using dind. I could not connect to my served app, as the exposed port 8000 was not exposed to my runner, but to the service defined in the gitlab-ci.yml. Thus I could connect with docker:8000 instead of localhost:8000

Answer (score 1):

Use "baseUrl":"http://host.docker.internal:3000"  in your cypress.json