# GitLab with Docker runner on localhost: how to expose host to container?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm learning to use GitLab CI.

Just now I'm using GitLab on localhost (`external_url "http://localhost"`). And I've registered a Docker runner with vanilla `ubuntu:20.04` image and tried to run some test job on it.

Alas, it tries to clone my repo from localhost repository in the container, but cannot do it, because my localhost's port 80 is not visible from container.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.5.0 (ece86343)
  on docker0 x8pHJPn7
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:20.04 ...
Pulling docker image ubuntu:20.04 ...
Using docker image sha256:d70eaf7277eada08fca944de400e7e4dd97b1262c06ed2b1011500caa4decaf1 for ubuntu:20.04 with digest ubuntu@sha256:fff16eea1a8ae92867721d90c59a75652ea66d29c05294e6e2f898704bdb8cf1 ...
Preparing environment
Running on runner-x8phjpn7-project-6-concurrent-0 via gigant...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/root/ci_fuss/.git/
fatal: unable to access 'http://localhost:80/root/ci_fuss.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
Uploading artifacts for failed job
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: report.xml: no matching files             
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

How can I can my Docker runner to expose host's localhost:80 as container's localhost:80?

Comment: Hope this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559660/gitlab-ci-runner-not-able-to-expose-ports-of-nested-docker-containers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, i have coped with this stuff.

I have added `network_mode = "host"`to my runner configuration in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` to make my docker use host network connections.

Also I've added `--pull_policy="if-not-present"` to first search for container image locally, then in remote repo.

```
[[runners]]
  name = "docker0"
  url = "http://localhost/"
  token = "TTBRFis_W_yJJpN1LLzV"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "exposed_ctr:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mode = "host"
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
```