# Docker outgoing traffic port mapping

Tags: linux, docker, networking, containers

I want to redirect all traffic from docker container to localhost and different port

Example: Within docker, some piece of code makes call to `google.com:443` , is it possible to redirect this traffic to `localhost:5000`. I am able to map hostname using `--add-host` argument in `docker run` command. But not sure about how to map port `443` to local port `5000`

Can someone please help on this

Comment: You could probably use IP tables here something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212807/iptables-forward-request-on-different-interfaces-and-port

Comment: Hey Thanks @ChrisDoyle . Do we run these `iptables` command inside docker or host machine